# My website says page not found after uploading of CSV file

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I am uploading CSV file which is having a lot of data nearly 20,000 rows. If I am upload lessthan 1000 rows then it is uploading successfully and redirect to the view page. If i am uploading 20,000 rows then it is uploading all the data and lastly it says page not found and not redirect to view page. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me.
It gives the error in console as

Mixed Content: The page at 'https:localhost/Client/upload_location' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is this effect my website?

```
I am just uploaded file and fetch records from csv file and inserting them into table.
$insert_array=array(
```

"location_name" =>$data[0]
);

$this->db->insert('locations', $insert_batch);

Comment: How much size [in megabyte or Kilobyte] of your CSV file?

Comment: The file size is 265Kb only

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... Provide code.